# Problem with TikZ externalize and \pause

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pause, external

I try to use `\pause` for TikZ pictures. Normally this works great, but since I have many pictures in my document, I also want to externalize the TikZ images. When I add the `\tikzexternalize` command, the `\pause` stops working:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % If this line is added, \pause stops to work

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (X) at (0,0) {x};
    \pause
    \node (Y) at (1,0) {y};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is this a general incompatibility?

I also tried `uncover` or `visible on`.

Comment: Every \pause creates a new slide, so you need two different tikzpictures.  I'm don't know how externalize names them, but somewhere you have a bunch of PDFs with tikzpictures in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that is not going to be fixed. See
https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/27/

There is an workaround provided by the developer in that bug report to keep working using `\tikzexternalize`: add `\only<2>{}` *after* the tikzpicture to force a second slide. Try the folloing:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % If this line is added, \pause stops to work

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (X) at (0,0) {x};
    \pause
    \node (Y) at (1,0) {y};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \only<2>{}% extra \pause to inner \pause to work.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, works! If using two `\pause`-items, a `\only<3>{}` does the job, etc. What does not work is a combination with `\tikzsetnextfilename`, because it then uses several times the same picture.